# Show a List of woocommerces products that have a product tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get a list of products to show up using the following code.

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && has_term( 'no-expedite', 'product_tag', $cart_item['product_id'] ) && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                $cat_in_cart = true;
                ob_start();
                echo '<ul> <li>'. wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) . '</li></ul>';
                $item = ob_get_clean();
                
            }
 //break;
}

// IF Tag is in cart or expedite disabled is True     
if ( $cat_in_cart || $expedite_disabled ) { 
$fields['billing']['noneexpediteableitems']['subtitle']='The following items can not be expedited:' . '<br>' .  $item . '<br>' . 'If you would like expedite the items not listed above, please remove the none expediteable items and order them seperatly.';
}
```

This code creates the list however if you try and capture the echo and put it in the var $item and use that var later it will only give you the last item on the list not the whole list.

Echo result (if you comment out ob_start(); & $item = ob_get_clean();) : https://ibb.co/VWJZKV9

Echo Var result: https://ibb.co/9ZdjTwN

Note 1 - We are using the Themehigh Checkout Field Editor to customize our checkout process.

Note 2 - This is just a section of the custom code it you would like to see more please let me know.

Comment: _"it will only give you the last item on the list not the whole list"_ - of course, because you are _overwriting_ $item all the time ... Properly initialize it with an empty string before the loop, and then _append_ to it - `$item .= ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Don't think this actually needs any output buffering to begin with. `$item .= '<ul> <li>'. wp_kses_post(...` should achieve the same result here.

Comment: @CBroe you are correct I was able to use your second option and it now show correctly. Thank you for your help, I Spent about 8 hours yesterday trying to figure that out.

I'm still pretty new at this so your help is much appreciated.